# Only "email" field can be passed via "id_token_hint" to B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm following [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/id_token_hint/tree/master/dotnet_core_symmetric_key) article to pass **email** and **displayName** as **id_token_hint** to my custom policy. Following is the technical profile I'm using to extract the data:

```xml
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims">
          <DisplayName> My ID Token Hint TechnicalProfile</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="None" />
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_ClientAssertionSigningKey" />
          </CryptographicKeys>  
          <OutputClaims>
            <!--Sample: Read the email cliam from the id_token_hint-->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="newUserEmail"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="displayName"/>
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Problem is, I'm only able to extract the email value. The **displayName** claim type not getting extracted. I checked the **id_token_hint** value in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms), value for both email and displayName is present there. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must also add the incoming claims as the input claims for the **RelyingParty** technical profile.

**Example**

```
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
  <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
    <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <!-- The following claims are read from the ID token -->
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="newUserEmail" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="displayName" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
      ...
    </OutputClaims>
    <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
  </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```